# Run celery periodic tasks on one machine only

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd

I am working on a django project where I am using celery. I have three two big modules in the project named app1 and app2. I have created two celery apps for that which are running on two separate machines. In the app1 and app2 there are different tasks which i want to run difference machines and it is working fine. But my problem is that i have some periodic_tasks. I have defined a queue named `periodic_tasks` for them. I want to run these periodic tasks on a separate third machine. Or on the third machine I want to run only the periodic tasks, and these periodic tasks shouldn't executed from the other two machines. Is it possible using celery.

Comment: If you have managed to configure celery so that app1 tasks are always run on a different machine than app2 tasks, why can't you do the same with your periodic tasks? There shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: periodic tasks are not in a different app, if those are related to app1 then those are in app1 or so on.

Answer (score 0):

On your third machine, make sure to start up celery with the `-Q` or `--queues` option with `periodic_tasks`.  On app1 and app2, start up celery without the `periodic_tasks` queue.  You can read more about queue handling here:  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-Q

Comment: Yes, I am trying this using `celery -A proj -Q periodic_tasks` , but when i see `celery inspect registered` it show me list of all the tasks from the complete projects.

Comment: Well, yeah, because all workers share a common broker, even if they don’t process all the tasks.